# Firebase Firestore can get and set when document already exist, but can not create when document not exist and can not create

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have firebase firestore with specific rule:
Allow read, write, create if user id match document id

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, create: if
          request.auth.uid != null &&
          request.auth.uid == resource.id;
    }
  }
}
```

And i try to get and set from android app with kotlin

```
private val db = Firebase.firestore
private val auth = Firebase.auth

val documentReference = db.collection("collectionPath").document(auth.uid!!)

documentReference.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        // get data and change something

        documentReference.set(dummy)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to SET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to GET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

It WORK WELL when document is already exist

But Error when document is not exist (Toast show Failed to GET)
the reason is PERMISSION_DENIED, this is what show in LogCat
`[Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(collectionPath/vlUray7W6rOsE11in621ADeF1Tu1 order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}`

I tried to create first but dont have permission too

```
// ...
val documentReference = db.collection("collectionPath").document(auth.uid!!)
documentReference.set(Dummy())
documentReference.get()
// ...
```

It still can not create even if match uid
`[Firestore]: Write failed at collectionPath/vlUray7W6rOsE11in621ADeF1Tu1: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}`

How can i create a document with uid